# Please focus, now

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, poetry

Take the helm,
be present,
remove your bib,
and do not blink
for the Dane is coming
and you must have your witz about you.

---

Hint 1

> The [history](/questions/tagged/history) tag would be appropriate.

Hint 2

> Consider alternate titles with the same meaning.

Hint 3 ([enigmatic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) spoiler)

> The title refers to a category, and each line refers to a thing in that category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think each line is referring to a

> [Nazi Concentration/Extermination camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extermination_camp)

Specifically

> A word from each line appears as a substring in the camp's name

Take the helm,

> C**helm**no

be present,

> **Be**lzec

remove your bib,

> So**bib**or

and do not blink

> Tre**blink**a

for the Dane is coming

> Maj**dane**k

and you must have your witz about you.

> Ausch**witz**-Birkenau

Title

> is a synonym for **concentrate**

Comment: That’s it! Great answer

Answer (score 2):

Have an idea that may be on track, or may be totally off:

Perhaps we are looking for:

> GUILDENSTERN or possibly GUILDENSTERN AND ROSENCRANTZ, or perhaps more generally as a directive to HAMLET himself, who Guildenstern and Rosencrantz are trying to get to "Pay attention!"

Take the helm,

> STERN is a synonym of HELM; take the stern, alluding to GUILDENSTERN
>  ('take' perhaps also alluding to 'work' and thus to 'guild')

be present,

> A synonym of 'be present' or 'please focus' is: "pay attention!"  Guildenstern and his cohort Rosencrantz were summoned by King Claudius in the play *Hamlet* to [distract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosencrantz_and_Guildenstern) him from his current madness. Hamlet was lost in his madness and they wanted him to 'be present' and divulge the source of his woes.
>  In Hamlet's well known speech to them, we see how he is not present:
>  Hamlet: *"I have of late, (but wherefore I know not) lost all my mirth, forgone all custom of exercises; and indeed, it goes so heavily with my disposition; that this goodly frame the earth, seems to me a sterile promontory; this most excellent canopy the air, look you, this brave o'er hanging firmament, this majestical roof, fretted with golden fire: why, it appeareth no other thing to me, than a foul and pestilent congregation of vapours.*"

remove your bib,

> This is a reference to fencing, removing the bib, or mask. Definitely relevant to Hamlet who does plenty of fencing in the play and hides behind his mask.

and do not blink

> Refers to staring, or watching closely. Guildenstern (and Rosencrantz) was recruited by King Claudius to be a spy and *watch Hamlet closely.*

for the Dane is coming

> In the play, Hamlet is known as "the Dane"

and you must have your witz about you.

> Guildenstern had his cohort Rosencrantz at his side, aiding his efforts. Both are witty, and I think 'wiTZ' clues 'rosencranTZ'.

Comment: This is an excellent guess, but not the answer I had in mind.

Comment: I've added a 3rd hint if you want another shot at it.